# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de crear la función Main en C?

Tags: c

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de escribir la función principal en C?

¿Así?:

```
main(){

}
```

¿O así?:

```
int main(){
return 0;
}
```

Porque no entiendo muy bien qué diferencia hay entre ambas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `main` sólo puede ser escrita de dos maneras en [c](/questions/tagged/c):

```
int main(void)
{
   ...

   return 0;
}
```

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ...

   return 0;
}
```

Cualquier otra manera no es estándar.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;**

Primeramente recordemos como es la definición de una función en `c`, que al final de cuentas, el `main` no es más que **la función principal**

```
tipo_resultado nombre_function(tipo_param1 param1, tipo_param2 param2, ... ) {
    ...
}
```

Para ver un ejemplo correremos este pequeño programa

```
#include <stdio.h>
int testear() {
    int variable = 8;
    return variable;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%i", testear());
}
```

Si corremos el programa podremos ver que nos imprimirá 8. Ya que hemos declarado que la función `testear` va a regresar un `int`.

Las funciones `int` si no se les asigna un valor de retorno, regresan por `default` 0. Veamos

```
#include <stdio.h>
int testear() {
    int variable = 8;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%i", testear());
}
```

En este ejemplo vemos que aunque no le pasemos algún `return` nos imprime `0`. Ya que como se mencionó, es el valor por **default** para las funciones de `return int`.

Ahora que pasa si no definimos el tipo, es decir de la siguiente manera.

```
#include <stdio.h>
testear() {
    int variable = 8;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%i", testear());
}
```

Podemos ver que esto nos regresa un `0` de todos modos, ya que el **tipo de variable de retorno** por **default** es un `int`. sin embargo podemos notar aquí el siguiente `warning`

```
 warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
```

Esto es debido a que desaconseja no regresar una variable de retorno, en `c` causa solo una advertencia y en `c++` causa un error.

Ahora que pasa si no queremos regresar una **variable de retorno**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void testear() {
    int variable = 8;
    printf("%i", 8);
}

int main()
{
    testear();
}
```

Podemos definir `void` que significa que la función no regresa ningún valor. De hecho si intentamos hacer lo siguiente.

#include <stdio.h>
void testear() {
int variable = 8;
printf("%i", testear());
}

```
int main()
{
    printf("%i", testear());
}
```

Podemos notar el error, dado que `testear` no regresaa ningún valor.

**RESUMEN**

En `c` se usa `int main(){return 0;}` y el número de retorno significa si tu programa se ejecutó de manera adecuada, dejando a 0 como `ejecución correcta` o regresando otro valor numérico que indican que la ejecución falló en algo.

`main(){...}` regresa lo mismo que `int main(){return 0;}` dado que si no se define **tipo de valor de retorno** en una función el **tipo de valor de retorno** es `int` por `default` y el valor por `default` para las funciones `int` cuando no se declara explícitamente es `0`. Sin embargo se desaconseja no definir **tipod e valor de retorno** en una función. Puedes usar `void main(){...}` si no deseas declarar una variable de retorno en tu función `main` sin embargo también en varias lados como en [este artículo](https://medium.com/@mdchandhyd/what-should-we-choose-int-main-void-main-main-c8474650b4c9) mencionan que de acuerdo al estándar ANSI de `C` no se debería usar `void main(){...}` por lo que la mejor opción es usar siempre `int main(){}`

Comment: Si le dices al compilador que sea estricto, te advierte al dejar una función sin `return`. https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw46LKzOvRKEktbhEQ7Oai6sWws9NzMwD8RWAoKAIKJKmoaSaoqQDVahpzVX7//@/5LScxPTi/7rhiTk5AA